# Is using Filestream a good idea?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have SQL Server 2012 and started looking into Filestream as a way to link "attachments" (> 1 GB) such as Excel documents and PDF files to database table records. While I have been successful in finding the "hello world" T-SQL examples that allow me to do some rudimentary tasks (enable Filestream, create table with Filestream column, insert row, etc.) I also encounter "beware" statements.

Is Filestream really as temperamental and full of "gotchas" as I the variously placed forum writings suggest, or is it straight forward and with a least predictable quriks?

Thank you for any insight

Comment: I have only used it once some time ago and it was somewhat complicated to use. I would go with filepath in DB instead and save the file on disk somewhere.

Comment: I agree with your sentiment. Did you find any advantages to Filestream, even if it appeared to be complicated?

Comment: I firmly believe that user files should be stored in the DB but I wouldn't dare give advice for storing 1+GB files.

Comment: The only advantage I notices is that the files got deleted on cascades.

Comment: Referential consistency is a big advantage.

Comment: @Stilgar, if we ignore the file size involved, did you find any advantage to Filestream?

Comment: @Stilgar SQL Server != File Server

Comment: @Workaholic I only needed to work with small files (profile pics, word documents, etc.) and I would never store them on the file system again if I had the choice. I store them in varbinary(max) since they are small and varbinary(max) is actually more efficient for files under 1MB.

In my opinion referential consistency is the most important thing. I actually wrote a post about it - http://sietch.net/ViewNewsItem.aspx?NewsItemID=124

Of course the post itself notes that if you have 1GB files you probably have a different problem.

Comment: The comments are helping me make a choice. Did anyone encounter any "gotchas" -- especially the type that should have been mentioned in instructional materials but typically isn't mentioned in print until much, much later?

Comment: We have been using Filestream with a web app for about 6 months now with exactly zero issues. SQL Server != File Server is correct... which is why it is better to store files in the file system and only reference them in the database... which is exactly what FILESTREAM does, only it saves you writing a whole lot of plumbing code.

Comment: Been using Filestream in production app for 2 years. Please read Microsoft's documentation showing the advantages of Filestream. There are definite performance advantages. In answer to the question about "gotchas": if you expect the Filestream to be store lots of files that will take up a lot of space, plan out your partitioning plan in advance. Also, these tips are good: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1875/best-practices-when-using-filestream-feature-of-sql-server-2008/

Comment: One of the advantages for me: size of files inserted in Filestream is not counted to the database limit in Sql Express

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using filetable which is implemented using filestream and its really neat enhancement, it preserves functionality of filestream but in contrast to filestream it can be configured to also allow accessing files outside db engine. For example, you can allow IIS to use those files directly. In production in big telecom company from 2013, flawless!

P.S. this is maybe more suitable for comment but I don't have reputation to write it :)